# insert a google maps link one for each event of fullcalendar js

Tags: javascript, c#, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

as the title suggests, I would like to insert and display a google maps link, stored in the db, different for each event of my full calendar v.3.1.0.I found many examples to insert static links, but never dynamically from the codebehind in c#.

Comment: You can add any custom properties you want to the event object when you're creating it (I assume you create the events from the c# code?). Then you can show the link on the screen using the eventRender callback. Or you can set the URL as the url property of the event which (as per the documentation) will mean the user is automatically navigated to that URL if they click on the event.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc for more info on all that.